# Strange behaviours in porting code from Eigen2 to Eigen3

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, eigen3

I'm considering to use [this](https://github.com/pthimon/clustering) library to perform spectral clustering in my research project.

But, to do so, I need to port it from Eigen2 to Eigen3 (which is what I use in my code).

There's a portion of code that is causing me some troubles.

This is for Eigen2:

```
double Evrot::evqual(Eigen::MatrixXd& X) {
    // take the square of all entries and find max of each row
    Eigen::MatrixXd X2 = X.cwise().pow(2);
    Eigen::VectorXd max_values = X2.rowwise().maxCoeff();

    // compute cost
    for (int i=0; i<mNumData; i++ ) {
        X2.row(i) = X2.row(i) / max_values[i];
    }
    double J = 1.0 - (X2.sum()/mNumData -1.0)/mNumDims;
    if( DEBUG )
        std::cout << "Computed quality = "<< J << std::endl;

    return J;
}
```

as explained [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Eigen2ToEigen3.html), Eigen3 replaces .cwise() with the slightly different .array() functionality.

So, I wrote:

```
double Evrot::evqual(Eigen::MatrixXd& X) {
    // take the square of all entries and find max of each row
    Eigen::MatrixXd X2 = X.array().pow(2);

    Eigen::VectorXd max_values = X2.rowwise().maxCoeff();

    // compute cost
    for (int i=0; i<mNumData; i++ ) {
        X2.row(i) = X2.row(i) / max_values[i];
    }
    double J = 1.0 - (X2.sum()/mNumData -1.0)/mNumDims;
    if( DEBUG )
        std::cout << "Computed quality = "<< J << std::endl;

    return J;
}
```

and I got no compiler errors.

But, if I give to the two programs the same input (and check that they're actually getting consistent inputs), in the first case I get numbers and in the second only NANs.

My idea is that this is caused by the fact that  `max_values` is badly computed and then using this vector in a division causes all the NANs. But I have no clue on how to fix that.

Can, please, someone explain me how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure X.cwise().pow(2); in eigen2 == X.array().pow(2); in eigen3?

Comment: According to the eigen wiki, this should be the natural conversion...

Comment: Then, of course, it's likely that I'm misinterpreting it. But I have no idea on how to do it differently!

Comment: "You can easily view a matrix as an array and vice versa using the MatrixBase::array() and ArrayBase::matrix() functions respectively." Shouldn't you use the `matrix()` function after `pow()`?

Comment: Just write `X2 = X.cwiseAbs2()`. `.pow(2)` is inefficient, as it calls `std::pow`, which essentially computes `exp(log(x)*2)`. I'm not sure why Eigen2 and Eigen3 behave differently here -- maybe in Eigen2 was a specialization for integer powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked when the values start to diverge ? Are you sure there is no empty rows or that X^2 do not underflow. Anyways, you should had a guard before dividing by `max_values[i]`. Moreover, to avoid underflow in squaring you could rewrite it like that:

```
VectorXd max_values = X.array().abs().rowwise().maxCoeff();
double sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<mNumData; i++ ) {
  if(max_values[i]>0)
    sum += (X.row(i)/max_values[i]).squaredNorm();
}
double J = 1.0 - (sum/mNumData -1.0)/mNumDims;
```

This will work even if `X.abs().maxCoeff()==1e-170` whereas your code will underflow and produces NaN. Of course, if you are in a such a case, maybe you should check your inputs first as you are already on dangerous side regarding numerical issues.

Comment: To be equivalent, I think it should be `(X.row(i)/max_values[i])` and `.array().abs2().sum()` could also be written as `.squaredNorm()`.